# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have a function that takes in a collection of `SearchCriteria` Objects:
columnName or Key, operator (`<`, `<=`, `like`, etc), and value.

The function builds up a Command Object.
I made the value a command parameter and now my Unit Tests will not work for Dates.
But all of my Unit Tests work against all other datatypes like varchar.

In the debugger, one of my date unit tests that fail end up with the cmd looking like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DocumentId 
               FROM idx1_AuthLetters a 
               INNER JOIN Documents b ON a.DocumentId = b.Id
               WHERE Status in ('L','S','V')  AND  letter_date <= :1 
               ORDER BY DOCUMENTID ) 
WHERE RowNum <= 14
```

I did have the parameter named like :letter_date.  But I might have :letter_date >= ### && :letter_date <= ### where I am looking between two dates. I cannot have the same parameter name twice so I use an i++ counter as parameter name while I am looping through all of my SearchCriteria Objects. Odd to see a parameter named like this I know but it is working for the most part.

If I take this and put in my Query Window, and look inspect the param value and plug that in:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DocumentId 
               FROM idx1_AuthLetters a 
               INNER JOIN Documents b ON a.DocumentId = b.Id 
               WHERE Status in ('L','S','V')  AND  
                     letter_date <= TO_DATE('2013-1-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
               ORDER BY DOCUMENTID ) 
WHERE RowNum <= 14
```

it works fine.
But it will not work from the C# code from my Unit Test.
Again this works for all other data types.
And it use to work before I parameterized the value in the select statement.

Exact error is:

> {"ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"}

Comment: In your C# code, what is the data type of the date parameter? If it's a string, how is it formatted - `yyyy-mm-dd`, `mm/dd/yyyy`, etc.?

Comment: Well it is not really a date parameter.  It is very generic.  Most of the time this is a varchar param.
But I check if it is a date field ahead of time and if so I pass the value to a parseDate function. I can take in 4 date formats but I always return it in the format to match my mask: yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: So in the above example, I am plugging in '2013-1-21. The SQL above has worked for along time. Not until I made it a command parameter did it stop working.  Also, like I say above, I can plug this into my query window and it executes ok. ODP.Net should not care if I am working with a date. All I am doing is plugging in the whole TO_DATE('2013-1-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd') into the :1 parameter placeholder.

Comment: If you're setting the parameter value to `myString`, try setting it instead to `DateTime.ParseExact(yourString, 'yyyy-MM-dd', null)` if that will fit within your existing framework. That way it'll be treated as a date and there shouldn't be any confusion over the formats.

Comment: Sorry Ed, I don't really understand whatyou mean. I do call a function like this to parse out the date:
                         if (columnDataType.ToUpper() == "DATE")
                    {
                        value = ParseDateFromValue(value);
                    }

Comment: Then my parse date function looks like this:

Comment: private string ParseDateFromValue(string value)
        {
            string[] format = { "yyyy-MM-dd", "MMddyyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
            DateTime valueDate;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out valueDate))
            {
                return valueDate.Year + "-" + valueDate.Month + "-" + valueDate.Day;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not parse incoming date: " + valueDate);
            }
         }

Comment: Then I add the value param: if (columnDataType == "DATE" && dataProvider == "Oracle.DataAccess.Client") { value = "TO_DATE('" + value + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd')"; }

Comment: I set the param name here:

Comment: string commandParamName;
                    if (dataProvider == "Oracle.DataAccess.Client")
                    {
                        commandParamName = ":" + i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commandParamName = "@" + i;
                    }

Comment: if (dataProvider == "Oracle.DataAccess.Client")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(commandParamName, value));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(commandParamName, value));
                    }

Comment: Do you have `value` as a generic (`var`) type? If so, you could change `ParseDateFromValue` to return a `DateTime` and just return `valueDate`. You have to put plain values into parameters (functions aren't allowed), which means that a parameter whose value is `TO_DATE('2013-1-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` will be rejected. Another option: if you have to keep it as a string the ANSI date format should work: `if (columnDataType == "DATE" && dataProvider == "Oracle.DataAccess.Client") { value = "DATE '" + value + "'"; }`

Comment: I don't really get this:

Comment: { value = "DATE '" + value + "'"; }

Do you mean "Date('" + value + "')  ?

Comment: No, I really meant the other way. You can't put a *function* into a parameter value, but you can put a *constant*, and Oracle recognizes `DATE '2013-1-21'` as a constant. Try it out: in your query window, take the last query from your question (the one that works) and replace the line `letter_date <= TO_DATE('2013-1-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` with `letter_date <= DATE '2013-1-21'`. You'll get the same result, but the first uses a function whereas the second uses a constant.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works in the Query Window. But it still gives me the same error in my Unit Test. A non-numeric number was found...

Comment: Bummer - I was hoping it would work without you having to change your approach. Here are some other options: (1) set the parameter value to a `System.DateTime` type, or (2) change the command in your first (non-working) example to `... AND letter_date <= TO_DATE(:1, 'YYYY-MM-DD)...` and then set the parameter value as a string like you're already doing. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks Ed for your feedback. I'll give this one a shot tomorrow.
AND letter_date <= TO_DATE(:1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
It makes it difficult because the client wanted the code to work against both Oracle and SQL Server. We just flip the swith for the connection string. So my :1 placeholder was working up until now for both DBs and all datatypes. It just blew up (only for dates on Oracle) once I made it a command param. I just need to find the msoet efficient way to generisize again. So I'll probably just comment out:

Comment: if (columnDataType == "DATE" && dataProvider == "Oracle.DataAccess.Client")
                    {
                        value = "TO_DATE('" + value + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd')";

Comment: and do my:
if (Oracle) // stuff:
Here:
 filter.AppendFormat(" {0} {1} {2} ", columnName, _operator, commandParamName);

Comment: Yes, you'll definitely need some serious "if SQL / if Oracle" code around the dates. The two have nothing in common when it comes to date types. Good luck!

Comment: Ed, thank you so much. This worked like a charm (at least in my DAL so far, unless I uncover something else) ; AND letter_date <= TO_DATE(:1, 'YYYY-MM-DD)
You totally saved my life here. Excuse my Oracle ignorance and sorry for posting so much code.

Comment: Actually though if anyone else is going through this, the date format is all lower case: 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: Sam - I'm glad this worked out! Best of luck going forward.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is really simple here:
In your command, build the following string `TO_DATE(:1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` . Then, just make sure that string that goes into `:1` has accurate format.

Your command text should be this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DocumentId 
           FROM idx1_AuthLetters a 
           INNER JOIN Documents b ON a.DocumentId = b.Id
           WHERE Status in ('L','S','V')  AND  letter_date <= TO_DATE(:1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  
           ORDER BY DOCUMENTID ) 
WHERE RowNum <= 14
```

Comment: @RichBianco I think, my answer covers that. your input didn't match your `Format Model`. Everything else - detail that is interesting for general knowledge but not as important to generate the fix. :-) Self quote: *"...make sure that string that goes into :1 has accurate format."* i.e. format model that matches input